# Arction lighningchart js saveToFile

Tags: lightningchart

When I call the screenShot function I get an error

> t.captureFrame is not a function

I know that the function header contains a engine: PublicEngine paramter but am I really supposed to pass that in?

the usage example seems to leave that part out e.g.

```
// Download 'screenshot.png'
saveToFile('screenshot')
// Attempt download 'maybeNotSupported.bmp'
saveToFile('maybeNotSupported', 'image/bmp')
// Attempt download jpeg.file with specified compression quality
saveToFile('fileName', 'image/jpeg', 0.50)
```

My function looks like this: (I am however making use of a wrapper function that calls screenShot and I tested that it gets to the saveToFile method.)

```
export function screenShot(fileName) {
    const lcjs = require('@arction/lcjs');
    const {
        saveToFile
    } = lcjs
    saveToFile(fileName, 'image/bmp');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to use the `saveToFile` functionality.

The first way is the way you have tried to use, by using the [`saveToFile`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/globals.html#savetofile) function. When using this function the [`PublicEngine`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/interfaces/publicengine.html) parameter is required as it specifies which chart instance to save. All charts that can be saved to file have [`engine`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/chartxy.html#engine) as a property so you can pass that from the chart you have created to save it to file.

```js
import { lightningChart, saveToFile } from '@arction/lcjs'
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()
saveToFile(chart.engine, 'Screenshot')
```

The other option, that can be nicer to use, is to use [`saveToFile`](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.4.0/classes/chartxy.html#savetofile) method that exists in all charts that can be saved to file.

```js
import { lightningChart } from '@arction/lcjs'
const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()
chart.saveToFile('Screenshot')
```

> the usage example seems to leave that part out e.g.

Looks like our documentation is incorrect for this method. This will be fixed in the next release.

*Disclosure: I work as a developer for LightningChart JS.*

Comment: Thank you, getting the engine from the chart and then passing it into the saveToFile method worked.
Edit: I think it is also noteworthy to mention that Typescript with a linter is great help as it would show what properties are available on the different objects.